# Ejabberd can't find include lib "p1_xml/include/

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have follow https://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_HTTP_request_handlers/ to create example, I have installed Ejabberd 14.07 on mac os. I have compile this program by using

```
erlc -I /Applications/ejabberd-14.07/lib/ejabberd-14.07/include -pz /Applications/ejabberd-14.07/lib/ejabberd-14.07/ebin mod_http_hello.erl
```

But when I compile I have found below Error Message.

```
/Applications/ejabberd-14.07/lib/ejabberd-14.07/include/jlib.hrl:22: can't find include lib "p1_xml/include/xml.hrl"
/Applications/ejabberd-14.07/lib/ejabberd-14.07/include/jlib.hrl:426: record xmlel undefined
/Applications/ejabberd-14.07/lib/ejabberd-14.07/include/jlib.hrl:466: type xmlel() undefined
```

I have Searched but didn't find any solution, If you any idea how to solve this error then guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved this issue, this is not the proper solution for this error, but I have spent 2 days to solve this so to work ahead I have used this solution. 
You can see that xml.hrl file is not found, so I have copied file content to jlib.hrl file, where it is included and it shows no error.

If you are confused about that xml.hrl file is not available so How can the content be copied then for that you have to follow steps to install ejabberd using command line. When you run "make command" it will add all dependencies.

GO to deps -> p1_xml-> xml.hrl

Answer (score 3):

i did the following to get it solved, at the source i ran `./rebar get-deps` and `./rebar compile` and then i copied the deps to the include folder

> cp -R  deps/* /lib/ejabberd/include/

after that i was able to compile my module just fine

Answer (score 1):

From 15.03, in order to fix this you must add an argument to erlc: `-DNO_EXT_LIB`

Comment: This, Thank you. The jlib header has an `ifdef` that will use `xml.hrl`, which exists for me instead of breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You missing some dependencies. Run `./rebar get-deps` in the root of the ejaberd source directory and look in the ./deps directory.

Comment: It did not work yet and did not even add dependencies. In deps folder I have found only cowboy related dependecies.

Comment: ok. try to run at first ``./configure`` and then ``make clean all`` in  the root of sources. it will get all missing sources and compile the whole project

Comment: First thanks for the reply, I don't have any file or folder with name of configure, But still I try it gives No Such File or Directory Error.

Comment: i guess that you need the fresh sources of ejaberd. http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads